# How to get all installed Windows updates names and KB numbers with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, updates

I need to get all installed Windows updates with PowerShell.

Result should contains update name, KB number, CVE id and severity rating.
I had try next scripts:
`Get-HotFix`,
`wmic qfe list`,
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering`.
But it returns only KB numbers.
Also I tried filter installed updates from next script result:
`Get-ChildItem -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages'`.
But this script return not all updates.

Next script don't return all installed Windows updates too:

```
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $HistoryCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
    $Updates = $Searcher.Search("IsPresent=1").Updates
    $Updates | ForEach-Object {$_}
```

I have no more ideas and I will be grateful for help.

Comment: how about: `(Get-Package -ProviderName msu -Force | Sort-Object Name -Descending).Name`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala unfortunately it returns not all updates too, but thanks for help.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? How do you know it doesn't return all updates?

Comment: @Abraham Zinala I compare returned result with list of updates in "Uninstall An Updates" from "Control Panel". Ideally I need all of this updates, but it seems unreachable ((

Comment: Then just run `Get-Package -Force`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PSWindowsUpdate](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.2) module in the PowerShell gallery. The `Get-WUHistory` cmdlet inside this module might just have everything you need.

Comment: It returns more fields but again not all updates, but thank you.